# Get group from D3js selectAll in console?

Tags: d3.js

In the context of understanding better the details of D3.js, I am a bit puzzled how `selectAll` works.

For example, based [on this codepen](http://codepen.io/mulderp/pen/aDrxq?editors=1111), it is possible to write:

```
vis.selectAll("circle.nodes")
```

or:

```
vis.selectAll("my_own_tag_group")
```

But after the D3js code is executed, I would expect that the `selectAll` gives a group that I could access from the web console too:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my_own_tag_group')
HTMLCollection [  ] (empty)
```

What am I missing from the explanations given in http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least from your code, it looks like you're doing the selection wrong. [`selectAll`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) follows [CSS3 selector rules](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp):

> D3 uses CSS3 to select elements. For example, you can select by tag ("div"), class (".awesome"), unique identifier ("#foo"), attribute ("[color=red]"), or containment ("parent child"). Selectors can also be intersected (".this.that" for logical AND) or unioned (".this, .that" for logical OR). If your browser doesn't support selectors natively, you can include Sizzle before D3 for backwards-compatibility.

Therefore, you'd probably want to use

```
vis.selectAll(".my_own_tag_group")
```

if it refers to a class, and

```
vis.selectAll("#my_own_tag_group")
```

if it refers to an id (which might either make sense or not).

If it refers to something else, you might want to restructure it so that it refers to a class.

Comment: this plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/ign1yLIWA8xrDFkJciP8?p=preview) proves that you can make a total bogus selection ;-). Look for the selectAll("boogy").

Comment: @ocket-san Very interesting! I'd say that, according to the documentation, it isn't very well defined, no? So, I guess in some cases it might do one thing, and, in another cases... something else. :-)

Comment: I never fully understood the documentation, so i really dont know the specific details on the selectAll :-). I would actually say that is quite data dependent, so i agree when you say that it does one thing in some cases and something else in an other case, depending on what you want to bind to it and what you want to do after the bind :-)

Comment: @ocket-san Nice experiment, I must say!

Comment: so "circle .node" selects the circle elements with the .node CSS class? but after the join, the resulting nodes miss the CSS class - so, the selection stays empty ?

Comment: @poseid Not sure I understand your last question. From what I understood of it, if "circle .node" comes empty, then the dom will show that there are no such elements. I suggest you 1. Start a separate question for that (SO is not built for a comment dialog), 2. Place a minimal JSFiddle. I'll be happy to have a look at it.

Comment: thanks! understood in the meanwhile, while playing with selections in the console.

Comment: @poseid Good for you! Sorry for the presumption, but that's the right way to go at it anyway.